# AwDataDirLock.java crashes thousands of times

Tags: android, webview, webkit

I have a crash that crashes thousands of times for multiple individual users.

This is the crash log directly from Firebase:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Using WebView from more than one process at once with the same data directory is not supported. https://crbug.com/558377 : Current process com.myAppName (pid 16059), lock owner  unknown
   at org.chromium.android_webview.AwDataDirLock.b(AwDataDirLock.java:106)
   at org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess.l(AwBrowserProcess.java:143)
   at com.android.webview.chromium.H.e(H.java:206)
   at vd4.run(vd4.java:337)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

as you can see below(screenshot from Firebase) I got 5.7k crash for 193 users:

[image: Firebase image]

I have been investigating this crash for a very long time and I have tried many solutions.

This usually happens to those who use AdMob, I don't use AdMob and I don't have any third-party libraries that use AdMob.

This is how I initialize the webview:
myApplication.kt onCreate()

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        var processName = getProcessName(applicationContext)
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(processName)) {
            processName = packageName + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis()
        }
        try {
            WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(processName!!)
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            //log
        }
    }

    private fun getProcessName(context: Context?): String? {
    if (context == null) return null
    try {
        val manager = context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        for (processInfo: ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo in manager.runningAppProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.pid == Process.myPid()) {
                return processInfo.processName
            }
            //log
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        //log
        return null
    }
    return null
}
```

I would be very happy to hear your opinion on why this happens and how it can be solved

Edit: This is the list of devices:

[image: This is the list of devices]

Comment: I am getting the same crash but on the splash screen and there is no WebView. so I think its something else. do share when you find anything